# Define database using a function as in Excel

Tags: database

Is there any Database that supports define columns (or fields) with functions similar to Excel?
For example 4th column MEAN is the mean value of the first three column.
Is this possible in SQL databases or is there any other database that supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. It should be possible with the use of trigger, which is supported in most of the databases. For details see the link. You can put formula in the trigger

[database trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223300/how-to-populate-mysql-column-value-based-on-a-formula)

Comment: Thank you. According to the link is 'View' a better choice? Do trigger and view support cascading, or is this simply a bad practice to use SQL...

Comment: Certainly trigger will slow down our insert/update, where as view will get affected during a select. The view will be executed on select...It's the implementation specific choice..