# dividing two columns and set the result in the third PHPMYADMIN?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I am new in PHP world, basically what I want to do is divide two columns and set the result automatically in a third column.

In my table 'Building' I have columns 'Selling' and 'Size'. I want to divide those two to get the Sell price per Sqm and set it in the column 'SqmPrice'.

Like this every time I input the price and the size it calculates it automatically and displays it in my web page.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223300/how-to-populate-mysql-column-value-based-on-a-formula

Comment: check the link i posted. it has what you want.

Comment: do you input values through phph ?

Comment: no I input throught my webpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two option

Option 1:
create a trigger that set the column to use the formula you assigned.
example

```
delimiter ~

create trigger my_table_insert before insert on tablename
for each row begin
    set new.sqmprice = new.Selling / new.Size; 
end~

delimiter ;
```

Option2:
Use php to calculate the value for formula and insert it

like this

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
$selling="2";
$size="2";
$SqmPrice = ($selling/$size);

$sql = "insert into tablename(Selling,Size,SqmPrice) values($sellin,$size,$SqmPrice) ";
$query = mysqli_query($sql,$con)or die(mysqli_error($con);
```

**NOTE**: Option2 does not update the sqmprice if the selling / size value is updated later

Comment: and like this the SqmPrice will be updated automatically eatch time I modify one of the tow field in the webpage ?

Comment: in that case you have to use option1. create a trigger.Becasue php code formulates only at the place it is used.

Comment: or when you modify one of the field update the `sqmprice` programmatically through php code.

Comment: I preffer the fisrt option, but I dont know how to do

Comment: i have added a trigger. use it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET SqmPrice=Selling/Size
```